# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue with Accounts framework

Tags: iphone, ios

I recently installed the latest Facebook iOS SDK and included the Accounts framework for use with it. While I don't think the issue is related to the Facebook iOS SDK, I thought I'd mention it.

The error I'm getting when I compile now is this:

> Pasting formed '_*MAC*@', an invalid preprocessing token

There are 3 of these errors, all within the Accounts framework header files that I cannot edit.

I'm using the default compiler: Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 with XCode version 4.6.3

I tried researching this issue for hours to no avail.

**UPDATE:** I tried compiling with Apple LLVM compiler 5.0 in XCode 5 Beta and I get even more compiler errors related to the Accounts framework.

**UPDATE:** I started a totally new project and rebuilt it from scratch. The same issue persists. As of now, it seems like my only option is to not use the new Facebook SDK or Accounts framework. I'm surprised no one else has this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I had a #define that looked like this in the pch file:

```
#define NA @"-"
```

Note to self. Do not use short define names in global header files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the Accounts.framework as "optional" under target settings?
Make it "Optional" and then Clean, Build and Run Project.

Comment: Still the same issue. I set as optional, then clean (no errors), but when I build, I still get the errors.